# Error in parsing soap request to Kotlin data class

Tags: android, soap, kotlin, retrofit2, simple-framework

Hi I am trying to make a soap request. I am using `Retrofit` and `SimpleXmlFactory` as the adapter. I have written the below data class for the soap request. But when making a request I am getting error like this:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Parameter 'soap:Body' does not have a match in class
```

Soap request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://myserver.com/webservices/">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <web:GetAvailablePasses>
            <web:securityToken>*****</web:securityToken>
            <web:userName>*****</web:userName>
            <web:password>*****</web:password>
        </web:GetAvailablePasses>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is my data class:

```
@Root(name = "soap:Envelope")
data class GetAvailablePassesRequest(
    @Element(name = "soap:Body", required = false)
    val body: MyRequest
)

@Root(name = "soap:Body", strict = false)
data class MyRequest(
    @Element(name = "web:GetAvailablePasses")
    val getAvailablePasses: GetAvailablePasses
)

@Root(name = "web:GetAvailablePasses")
data class GetAvailablePasses(
    @Element(name = "web:securityToken")
    var securityToken: String,
    @Element(name = "web:userName")
    var userName: String,
    @Element(name = "web:password")
    var password: String
)
```

This is my ApiService interface:

```
@POST("FlashPassAPI.asmx")
    fun getAvailablePasses(@Body request: GetAvailablePassesRequest): Single<GetAvailablePassesResponse>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried that but it didnt solve the problem. @SohelS9

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Body" instead of "soap:Body" in your code, let me know if it works

```
@Root(name = "soap:Envelope")
data class GetAvailablePassesRequest(
    @Element(name = "Body")
    val body: MyRequest
)

@Element(name = "soap:Body")
data class MyRequest(
    @Element(name = "web:GetAvailablePasses")
    val getAvailablePasses: GetAvailablePasses
)

@Element(name = "web:GetAvailablePasses")
data class GetAvailablePasses(
    @Element(name = "web:securityToken")
    var securityToken: String,
    @Element(name = "web:userName")
    var userName: String,
    @Element(name = "web:password")
    var password: String
)
```

Just copy and paste the above code in your data class.

Comment: I tried but didnt work. @Sayan

Comment: could you tell me what error is showing?

Comment: Got it fixed by making `@Element` to `@field:Element`

Comment: could you please add an answer to your question so that other beginners find it helpful?